# WAMPServer 404s a directory URL unless it ends with a trailing slash

Tags: apache2, wampserver

How can I set Apache so that it doesn't require the trailing slash on the end of the directory?

e.g. `http://localhost/test` will result in 404, whereas `http://localhost/test/` will display the `index.html` file for that directory.

**Update:**

I should add that the example `/test/` directory is in fact an alias.

Comment: After downloading WampServer and adding a new directory named `test` within the standard `www` directory, it displays the directory contents just fine with or without the trailing slash (i.e., no `404` errors).  Same thing when I add an `index.html` inside of `test`. Are you possibly using a different directory than `www`? If so, you'll need to create an [Alias Directory](http://willi.am/blog/2009/01/14/wamp-alias-directories/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just noticed @dan's comment above. If `/test/` is indeed an Apache Alias, as set by WAMPServer, then the `DirectorySlash` may not be the problem after all. Both solutions are presented below.

---

## `DirectorySlash` directive

You need to set `DirectorySlash On` in your Apache config (or .htaccess). This instructs mod_dir to implicitly append a slash in the case you mention; when the URL points to a directory.

However, this is normally `On` by default, so it's likely there is a `DirectorySlash Off` somewhere that is explicitly disabling this? So it may be preferable to find this and simply remove it.

Reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

---

## Apache `Alias` set by WAMPServer

The solution regarding the Apache `Alias` (as set by WAMPServer) is contained in the [Wamp Alias Directories](http://willi.am/blog/2009/01/14/wamp-alias-directories/) article as linked to by @dan in the comments above.

An [Apache `Alias` (mod_alias)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) allows you to serve files from a different location on your filesystem as if they are stored under the document root. So, in the case of the `/test` directory above, this (as it turns out) is an *alias* for a different location on the local filesystem.

WAMPServer provides its own interface for creating this `Alias`. However, in doing so it appears to append a slash to the URL-path, so `/test` becomes `/test/`. This means that you will need to also append this slash to the requested URL, otherwise it will not match!

The solution to this is to manually edit the *alias file* and remove this slash. From the linked article:

> Click on the Wamp Server tray icon again and select Apache → Alias directories → [alias url] –> Edit alias. This will open the alias file in Notepad. Remove the trailing slash from the relative URL.

Reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias
http://willi.am/blog/2009/01/14/wamp-alias-directories/

Comment: Hi w3d, dan - sorry, I neglected to mention that it's an alias. N00b error (I've updated the question for clarification). I had a look in httpd.conf for DirectorySlash but there was no mention of it at all, anyway. Fortunately, the blog post which dan links to provides an answer - "open the alias file in Notepad. Remove the trailing slash from the relative URL...  you’re alias should now work with or without the trailing slash". I can confirm that it works!

Comment: I've modified the answer to include the information about the Apache `Alias` from the linked article.